# how to add custom menu options in naviagtion menu in android studio like below image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigationview

[image]

Here I can able to do this one, But in some phones, the menu lists are overlapping with below linear layout list. So is there any other approach where I can achieve this thing where it will come below to that menu list.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/morewhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/morewhite"
    android:background="@mipmap/menubac"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.titleColor"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feedbackitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/morewhite"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Feedback" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logoutitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/morewhite"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Logout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried using layout constraints? In my opinion, it is better to use constraint layout because of its flexibility across multiple phone screens